# creating a facebook pages like app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails app where users can sign up and create posts, now what i want to achieve is that i want to give users option to create pages and those pages will be able to create post, what i have done till now is i have generated another controller called pages i have added users to that pages by doing a migration.

Relationship between modals look like:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :google_oauth2]

         act_as_mentionee

  validates :username, presence: true
  validate :avatar_image_size

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**pages.rb**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :description, :user_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    delegate :username, to: :user
end
```

**posts.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  act_as_mentioner

  validates :title, :body, :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :channel
end
```

Now i want to add posts to pages and i really don't know how to do that, i want to add posts in pages so pages can create post.

what will be the best way to go around this?
and if you know some kind of tutorial or gem for this please tell me.

Comment: you need help in creating views and linking them to controllers ?

Comment: yup...am really new, am trying to learn by doing this

Answer (score 0):

First you need add a controller for User Model

to add a controller you can refer this rails guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

once controller is added you need to add your routes in routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

You need to add the corresponding views for each action in controller

In user model you can add

nested attributes for the :pages and :posts

see the below help document for nested attributes

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Hope this answer gives you some idea on how to proceed further